# LDAP: Operating an multi-site Login server

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I am working on a project in order to provide an internet service for unified user logins, which is going to be implemented using LDAP. Only some website administrators, who I trust, will get access to it.

I already started with the concept:

- Inside the BaseDN are accounts for the privileged sites e.g. example1.com, example2.com
- The accounts will be created as a organizationalRole objectClass, so that additional user accounts can be stored inside
- In case the password of a website owner gets compromised or a Captcha function is not working, the password of the privileged account can be replaced so that there is no possiblity to add new accounts or to change the current ones.
- Creating an ACL (=Access Control List) to only allow them writing to their own directory

Unfortunately, I also noticed that this is not the best way.

- I don't know if I can "search" through all directories for a certain username, so that `cn=example1.com` has access to the users in `cn=example2.com`.
- When someone gets access to the password of a website, all the user can be deleted as far as I know.

What would be the best way to protect these accounts? How are you thinking about my concept? How can I improve this?

Comment: You should SERIOUSLY consider using one of identity as a Service (IDaaS) providers. If you must create your own LDAP, then put OpenID Connect in front of LDAP.